# Opening a website is getting delayed

Tags: web, page-load-time

First of all thanks to everyone who have supported me in this forum to solve critical issues and thanks in advance for this question.

I am building a website http://kidneyprostate.com where I have used wordpress too. The **index** file is a php file which is HTML5 and the **all other files** are in **Wordpress**.

What I have done I have kept all other files including the blog in a **Subfolder** named as [http://kidneyprostate.com/kidney-prostate.com/](http://kidneyprostate.com/kidney-prostate.com) inside the root folder.

I found everything worked fine. But after few days my server got Bandwith Speed exceeded and my host company rectified it.

Now what I am facing that the site is getting delayed to open. I have checked with **Pingdom Tools** and I have optimized the images (those for slides), Minified the CSS and Javascript files. But still the delay problem persists.

Reasons I am guessing may be due to the same name of the sub folder or the bandwith speed have not yet been totally rectified.

Can you please help me that am I guessing correct or any other issues?
If my naming of the subfolder i.e. kidney-prostate.com is not the right way then after changing the name of the subfolder will work?

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "same-name" url has nothing to do.

```
1) Use a cache plugin (I would recommend WP Super Cache) and deactivate all the unnecessary plugins. 
2) Delete all the unused themes and images.
3) Also I would consider that you deactivate some heavy bandwidth plugins (like google-analytics ones)
```

Comment: Thanks Nik I think I must go for it, but the cache plugin shall meet the purpose?

Comment: Nik which is the best cache plugin. What do you suggest. Any help?